# Can't compile my library because "String does not name a type"

Tags: library, esp8266

I am writing a small library to move some code out of the arduino sketch and make it reusable. Problem is that it does not compile since "String does not name a type".

This is my code (reduced):

myESP.h:

```
#ifndef MYESP_H
#define MYESP_H

#include "Arduino.h"

#include <String>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <WiFiServer.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
 
class myESP {
    private:
        const char* _ssid;
        const char* _password;
        const char* _host;
    public:
        myESP();
        myESP(char * ssid, char * pwd, char * host);
        String macToStr(const uint8_t* mac);
        String doGet(String data, String sensor, int duration);
};
#endif
```

myESP.cpp:

```
#include <String>

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "myESP.h"

myESP::myESP() {}

myESP::myESP(char * ssid, char * pwd, char * host) {
    _host = host;
    _password = pwd;
    _ssid = ssid;
}

myESP::String macToStr(const uint8_t* mac) {
}

myESP::String doGet(String data, String sensor, int duration) {

}
```

When i try to compile it, I get the following:

> /Users/lbedogni/Documents/Arduino/libraries/myESP/myESP.cpp:14:1:
> error: 'String' in 'class myESP' does not name a type  myESP::String
> macToStr(const uint8_t* mac) {
>
> /Users/lbedogni/Documents/Arduino/libraries/myESP/myESP.cpp:22:1:
> error: 'String' in 'class myESP' does not name a type  myESP::String
> doGet(String data, String sensor, int duration) {

I have tried to change the order of the imports, change libraries, but still it does not compile.

Any idea?

Comment: `#include <String>` - the IDE automatically includes the `String` type so you don't need this include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong in myESP.cpp. Change this:

```
myESP::String macToStr(const uint8_t* mac) {
}

myESP::String doGet(String data, String sensor, int duration) {

}
```

to this:

```
String myESP::macToStr(const uint8_t* mac) {
}

String myESP::doGet(String data, String sensor, int duration) {

}
```

The return type is `String` and the function implementation should be prefixed with the class name `myESP::`. Obviously, you also need to fill in the body of the implementation or you'll get more errors because you don't actually return anything.